# Edit controls won't get focus! win32 c++

Tags: c++, winapi, edit

Edit Control's in my Win32 App just refuse to take focus!. As a result, I cannot enter text in them. The controls worked fine before, and now just refuse to work!
Here's a link to the code:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35856163/src.zip

Comment: You say they worked before, but not now. What has changed? Your question could really use some details, perhaps even code snippets.

Comment: You have waaaay too much code in headers and none of it is marked as inline.  I'm guessing you are a Java programmer...

Comment: @viraj: You need put up a minimal code snippet that demonstrates the problem into your question. Seriously, we're not going to have the time nor patience to read and understand what's going on, much less downloading a zip file containing way too much code for us to take just to answer this question. Try to narrow down the scope of the problem and see if you can isolate it and make a minimal, compilable code snippet of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time post code right here, and at least try to compile it! I get 18 errors just trying to compile your file. Your code is also very hard to read, so I can't really say what happens where. You are mixing chars with wchars_t thus you can have memory corruption. `char Buffer[Length() + 1];` shouldn't even compile! What compiler are you using? For dynamic allocation you MUST use pointers and new keyword, you can't use array subscript for dynamic size.

Anyway I maybe know where the problem lies - you're missing TranslateMessage before DispatchMessage. That bugs whole message thing and you of course can't get correct messages.

Comment: +1 just for taking the time to download and compile that mess.

Comment: These arrays are called VLAs and are part of C99. I imagine the poster is using the gnu compiler.

Comment: There's also a method that goes `GetFocus() { SetFocus(Handle); }` That's where I gave up.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks for pointing that out for me, I didn;t know such thing even exist, because MSVC immediately gives error: "unknown size". Still I think using such technique is quite bad while working with c++.

Comment: Im using MinGW.
Thank you so much for you're help. i apologize for posting all of the code as a .zip file, but I couldn't isolate where the problem was.
I'm just starting out, and haven't really written long ( > 200 lines) programs before.
I apologize, once again.
@Raymond: Thank you for taking the time to read it! :) The reason the code is so messed up is because I have encapsulated the Win32 controls into my own classes, (and rather shoddily at that).

Comment: so it was actually due not calling TranslateMessage or something else fixed it?

Comment: Yes, the problem was with not calling TranslateMessage. It works fine now.